# Expo.io - Is an app running on the expo app one to one comparable to a standalone app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm gonna use Expo to make an app, and share preliminary results with a client. I want to tell them that this expo app mirrors the final app, that will be available as a standalone app for my client's clients, one to one.

The functionality of the app will be basic, and I will keep its functionality well within the current capabilities of react-native and expo.

Apart of course from the downloading and building part of the expo app, can I say that this expo app is one on one comparable to the standalone app? Or are there gotchas that I and my client have to take into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you stay within Expo without detaching, the app should be exactly what you'll deliver on the store.